# How to do a interpolation by using thresholds with python?

Tags: python, interpolation, threshold

I want to do a special interpolation by using thresholds with python:
Here you can see the part of my code:

```
x=np.arange(0,len(x_values[:-2]))    
f = interpolate.interp1d(x,derivation)
xnew = np.arange(0, len(x_values[:-3]),0.01)
ynew = f(xnew)
plt.plot(x, derivation, "o",xnew, ynew, "-")
```

Then I get the following plot:
[image]

With Paint I drew red circles in the places I want to remove (there are probably more places).
The task is to solve this with interpolation using thresholds. Unfortunately I don't know how to solve this with thresholds. Could somebody help me, please?

The blue points in the plot are my data (I have discrete values). So it is always a point that needs to be removed using the task described above.

Thanks for helping me! :)

`x_values` is the following array:

```
[0.  , 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 ,
       0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 , 0.21,
       0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3 , 0.31, 0.32,
       0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.41, 0.42, 0.43,
       0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.5 , 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54,
       0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.6 , 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65,
       0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.7 , 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76,
       0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 , 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87,
       0.88, 0.89, 0.9 , 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98,
       0.99, 1.  , 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09,
       1.1 , 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 1.2 ,
       1.21, 1.22, 1.23, 1.24, 1.25, 1.26, 1.27, 1.28, 1.29, 1.3 , 1.31,
       1.32, 1.33, 1.34, 1.35, 1.36, 1.37, 1.38, 1.39, 1.4 , 1.41, 1.42,
       1.43, 1.44, 1.45, 1.46, 1.47, 1.48, 1.49, 1.5]
```

and `derivation` is the following array:

```
[9.88,   -2.12,   29.88,   -2.12,    9.88,   16.88,    9.88,
          4.88,    9.88,   -2.12,    9.88,   16.88,   10.88,    9.88,
         10.88,    9.88,    4.88,    3.88,   -2.12,    9.88,    3.88,
         10.88,   10.88,    9.88,    9.88,   10.88,   10.88,   15.88,
         16.88,   16.88,   22.88,   34.88,   41.88,   53.88,   60.88,
         -2.12,   72.88,   84.88,   97.88,  110.88,  128.88,  141.88,
        159.88,  172.88,  191.88,  203.88,  222.88,  241.88,  266.88,
        272.88,  297.88,  303.88,  322.88,  303.88,  279.88,  240.88,
        166.88,   97.88,   22.88,  -46.12,  -64.12,  -90.12, -139.12,
       -134.12, -164.12, -190.12,   -2.12, -202.12, -226.12, -221.12,
       -227.12, -234.12, -214.12, -214.12, -215.12, -215.12, -208.12,
       -196.12, -189.12, -183.12, -184.12, -189.12, -183.12, -177.12,
       -165.12, -152.12, -146.12,   -2.12, -152.12, -170.12, -171.12,
       -177.12, -171.12, -177.12, -170.12, -159.12, -133.12, -108.12,
        -77.12,  -52.12,  -27.12,   -8.12,   21.88,   47.88,   -2.12,
         73.88,   84.88,   91.88,  109.88,  122.88,  103.88,  110.88,
        110.88,  109.88,  109.88,  110.88,   91.88,   78.88,   66.88,
         53.88,   47.88,   34.88,   29.88,   -2.12,   22.88,   22.88,
         15.88,   16.88,   10.88,    3.88,    9.88,    4.88,   -2.12,
         16.88,   -2.12,    3.88,  -15.12,   -8.12,  -15.12,   -8.12,
         -8.12,   -2.12,   -8.12,   -8.12,   -9.12,   -8.12,   -8.12,
         -2.12,   -9.12]
```

**EDIT**

If I use `kind='nearest'` then it looks like this:
[image]

That's a little bit strange and also not what I want to have in the end.

Comment: have you tried changing the type of interpolation?

Comment: As far as i understood you dont want those peaks to be part of your interpolation right?

Comment: I have tried to interpolate the function. But my task is to interpolate the function using thresholds to remove these peaks or the outliers. Unfortunately I have no idea how to handle the thresholds in a way that the interpolation removes these spots and smoothes the function.

Comment: I also have the feeling that the interpolation function I used here has not really done anything so far. If I make a normal plot, i.e. just let the values be plotted as normal, I get the same function progression.

Comment: When I use `kind='nearest'`  the following happens (see Edit in my question)

Comment: @mathsqt You are probably more interested in `kind='quadratic'` or `kind='cubic'`.

Comment: @ChrisMueller ive tried few, ur method seems way better than using inbuilt functions tbh

Comment: I think the peaks I mean are at -2.12 on these data. But this can be different with other data. But it is noticeable, and this is also the case with my other data, that they are very close to 0.

Comment: @ombk what means tbh?

Comment: How can I delete this peaks by use interpolation (with thresholds maybe)? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following chris' suggestion, I have used the medfilt to interpolate using the median. with a `window` of 3.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.signal import medfilt
z = medfilt(derivation,3)
x=np.arange(0,len(x_values[:-2]))    
f = interp1d(x,z,kind="linear")
xnew = np.arange(0, len(x_values[:-3]),0.01)
ynew = f(xnew)
plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
plt.plot(x, z,"o",xnew, ynew, "-")
```

[image]

```
# filtering based on threshold
diff = abs(derivation-z) #shows the difference between the smoothed array and the original one. 
new_smootheddata = np.where(diff>50,z,derivation)
x=np.arange(0,len(x_values[:-2]))    
f = interp1d(x,new_smootheddata,kind="linear")
xnew = np.arange(0, len(x_values[:-3]),0.01)
ynew = f(xnew)
plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
plt.plot(x, z,"o",xnew, ynew, "-")
```

[image]
In the new image, we can notice that the smoothing just happens for the points that had very high peaks (following our filtered set based on a threshold of `>50` , however, we can lower this threshold as much as we want.
`new_smootheddata = np.where(diff>50,z,derivation)` this line means that if the `diff>50` then choose the `z` value which is `smoothed`, else choose the original data.

***How to keep the original point showing***

[image]

Comment: You are amazing :) Thank you! I will try it.

Comment: @mathsqt watch out from the window size, going too big will make ur plot very smoothed, so stay at 3 values. ^_^

Comment: to make it better btw, you can now follow exactly what chris said, apply a threshold between the newly smoothed list and the previous one. IF different is very big, keep the value of the newly smoothed (if u want help in that i can do it and explain all but i need some time)

Comment: I need some explanation to understand what thus really means with the threshold.

Comment: @mathsqt all explained.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps a lot.

Comment: Good job on the implementation!

Comment: Yes, on the second picture I was just wondering what about the other spikes.

Comment: @mathsqt re-read everything said you will understand. make sure to read the code also in detail. The small other spikes are due to the fact that we made the `threshold` just focus on big spikes `>50`  difference between the `original` and `median_smoothed`

Comment: yeah ok... now I understand all :) thank you!

Comment: I have now taken a closer look at this. In my output values or function (see plot in my question), for example, there is a peak at approx. y=320 and x=50. This peak is no longer there now. But this is actually not quite correct. I only wanted to remove the outliers. In the plot in my question I marked a selection of them with red circles (to avoid confusion: that means there are even more than the ones I had drawn there).

Is it possible to solve this without the median and only with interpolation (over two values each??) and threshold value?

Comment: @mathsqt interpolate using z, draw the graph using x,y original and the interpolation using the xnew,ynew where z is applied. your o will stay there but wont be linked

Comment: @mathsqt check the answer again now :p[

Comment: I've been thinking about this again. Can you tell me why you just chose the window size of the median filter with 3 and also why you chose 50 as threshold? What can I imagine under these two values?

Answer (score 1):

My approach to your problem would be the following:

1. Apply a median filter to `derivation` with a window of 5 or 7.  This will return a new array of the same size as `derivation`, let's call it `filtered_derivation`.
2. Calculate the absolute value of the difference between `derivation` and `filtered_derivation`.  Examine the data and decide on an appropriate threshold.
3. Remove all points in `derivation` which fall outside of the threshold you determine.
4. Perform your interpolation on the `derivation` array with the outliers removed.

Comment: Could you explain to me how the threshold value is meant and what it should look like (maybe with a short drawing)? Please.

Comment: @mathsqt if my solution solves your issue, select chris' answer as `answer` please. I only implemented his logic.